# d3 heatmap not showing title unless datset button is clicked

Tags: d3.js

I have a d3 heatmap component(followed the tutorial [here](http://bl.ocks.org/tjdecke/5558084)) but it does not have the tooltip(the title attr).I think `cards.select("title").text((d) => d.value);`  is not working.When I inspect I cant see the title being appended.In the tutorial itself on initial load the tooltip is not present(loads only when you click on the button datasets).Can someone help me fix this.

```
ngOnInit() {
            this.margin = { top: 50, right: 0, bottom: 100, left: 30 },
            this.width = 960 - this.margin['left'] - this.margin['right'],
            this.height = 430 - this.margin['top'] - this.margin['bottom'],
            this.gridSize = Math.floor(this.width / 24),
            this.legendElementWidth = this.gridSize*2,
            this.buckets = 9,
            this.colors = this.heatMapConfig["colors"];
            this.days = this.heatMapConfig["days"];
            this.times = this.heatMapConfig["times"];
            this.datasets = ["data.tsv", "data2.tsv"];

          this.svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
              .attr("width", this.width + this.margin['left'] + this.margin['right'])
              .attr("height", this.height + this.margin['top'] + this.margin['bottom'])
              .append("g")
              .attr("transform", "translate(" + this.margin['left'] + "," + this.margin['top'] + ")");

          let dayLabels = this.svg.selectAll(".dayLabel")
              .data(this.days)
              .enter().append("text")
                .text( (d) =>{ return d; })
                .attr("x", 0)
                .attr("y", (d, i) =>{ return i * this.gridSize; })
                .style("text-anchor", "end")
                .attr("transform", "translate(-6," + this.gridSize / 1.5 + ")")
                .attr("class",  (d, i) =>{ return ((i >= 0 && i <= 4) ? "dayLabel mono axis axis-workweek" : "dayLabel mono axis"); });

          let timeLabels = this.svg.selectAll(".timeLabel")
              .data(this.times)
              .enter().append("text")
                .text((d) =>{ return d; })
                .attr("x", (d, i)=> { return i * this.gridSize; })
                .attr("y", 0)
                .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + this.gridSize / 2 + ", -6)")
                .attr("class", (d, i) =>{ return ((i >= 7 && i <= 16) ? "timeLabel mono axis axis-worktime" : "timeLabel mono axis"); });

          let datasetpicker = d3.select("#dataset-picker").selectAll(".dataset-button")
            .data(this.datasets);

          datasetpicker.enter()
            .append("input")
            .attr("value", (d)=>{ return "Dataset " + d })
            .attr("type", "button")
            .attr("class", "dataset-button")
            .on("click", (d) =>{
              this.heatmapChart("assets/tsv/data.tsv");// this works
            });
            this.heatmapChart("assets/tsv/data.tsv"); //I tried calling this function here,but doesnt work.
        }

        private heatmapChart(tsvFile) {  

            d3.tsv(tsvFile,
            (d) =>{
              return {
                day: +d.day,
                hour: +d.hour,
                value: +d.value
              };
            },
            (error, data)=> {
              const colorScale = d3.scaleQuantile()
            .domain([0, this.buckets - 1, d3.max(data, (d) => d['value'])])
            .range(this.colors);
         const cards = this.svg.selectAll(".hour")
              .data(data, (d) => d.day+':'+d.hour);


          cards.enter().append("rect")
              .attr("x", (d) => (d.hour - 1) * this.gridSize)
              .attr("y", (d) => (d.day - 1) * this.gridSize)
              .attr("rx", 4)
              .attr("ry", 4)
              .attr("class", "hour bordered")
              .attr("width", this.gridSize)
              .attr("height", this.gridSize)
              .style("stroke", "#E6E6E6")
              .style("stroke-width", "2px")
              .style("fill", this.colors[0])
              .merge(cards)
              .transition()
              .duration(1000)
              .style("fill", (d) => colorScale(d.value));


          cards.select("title").text((d) => d.value);// not working 

          cards.exit().remove();

        const legend = this.svg.selectAll(".legend")
              .data([0].concat(colorScale.quantiles()), (d) => {
                  return d;});

          const legend_g = legend.enter().append("g")
              .attr("class", "legend");

          legend_g.append("rect")
            .attr("x", (d, i) => this.legendElementWidth * i)
            .attr("y", this.height)
            .attr("width", this.legendElementWidth)
            .attr("height", this.gridSize / 2)
            .style("fill", (d, i) => this.colors[i]);

          legend_g.append("text")
            .attr("class", "mono")
            .text((d) => "≥ " + Math.round(d))
            .attr("x", (d, i) => this.legendElementWidth * i)
            .attr("y",this.height + this.gridSize);

          legend.exit().remove();
      };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a tutorial, that is just a bl.ocks.

The problem you described seems to be a minor mistake by the author. It can be solved by simply moving this line...

```
cards.append("title");
```

... for **after** the enter selection which append the rectangles.

Here is the updated bl.ocks, now it shows the `<title>` element *the first time* the code runs: http://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/f9eac64ec2f962f2cada6456478740f7

EDIT: since you are using D3 v4.x, you cannot anymore rely on the *magic of the enter selection*, introduced in D3 v2 but removed in v4.

Thus, because you're using a transition selection, give a name to your "enter" selection:

```
var cardsEnter = cards.enter().append("rect")
    .attr("x", (d) => (d.hour - 1) * gridSize)
    .attr("y", (d) => (d.day - 1) * gridSize)
    .attr("rx", 4)
    .attr("ry", 4)
    .attr("class", "hour bordered")
    .attr("width", gridSize)
    .attr("height", gridSize)
    .style("fill", colors[0]);

cardsEnter.append("title").text((d) => d.value);

cardsEnter.merge(cards)
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .style("fill", (d) => colorScale(d.value));

cards.select("title").text((d) => d.value);
```

Here is the bl.ocks using v4: http://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/de9ff9b1345a78b665f9e001691ab0ce

Comment: still not working for me :( . I have used the npm package d3 - import * as d3 from 'd3';

Comment: Well, you have another problem then: you can clearly see that it **is** working in my bl.ocks, and it's not working in the original bl.ocks.

Comment: Also, in the code you shared you never append any title.

Comment: cards.append("title");
          cards.transition().duration(1000)
              .style("fill", function(d) { return colorScale(d.value); });
          this line also doesnt work for me

Comment: why doesnt - "cards.transition().duration(1000) .style("fill", function(d) { return colorScale(d.value); }); " this work for me?

Comment: I have no idea of what you're asking. Have in mind that your code uses D3 v4, where the bl.ocks uses v3. Unlike v3, you have to append the title to the "enter" selection for the rects.

Comment: http://bl.ocks.org/ganezasan/dfe585847d65d0742ca7d0d1913d50e1 this uses v4,but the title is not appended.I tried moving the append title to after the "rect" part, but still doesnt work.Can you please help me.Thanks for your answer.

Comment: How can I write it in v4? this - http://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/8d486b5c7d3020f38094247ce38d4779 does not seem to work.

Comment: Since you're using a transition selection, just drop the `merge`: http://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/89f70c44cb13c255a2d16d2a7ba57239